# numpy typing works locally but not in circleci

Tags: numpy

I have numpy 1.22.4 installed locally and I changed the output of the expected methods from

```
def _predict(self, X: pd.DataFrame) -> np.array:
```

to

```
def _predict(self, X: pd.DataFrame) -> np.typing.ndarray:
```

When I execute locally `mypy feature_engine` the tests pass. But when committing the code to the repo, and the tests run in circle ci, they do not pass, because of the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typing'
```

When I check the circleci environment, it seems to be working with numpy 1.22.4 as well:

[image]

Any idea why this could be happening?

For reference, this is the [PR](https://github.com/feature-engine/feature_engine/pull/476) in question. These are the versions I have locally:

```
Python version: 3.10.3
Numpy version: 1.22.4
Pandas version: 1.4.2
Scikit-learn version: 1.1.1
Scipy version: 1.8.1
Statsmodels version: 0.13.2
Mypy version: 0.961
```

And the error thrown locally when I do not update from np.array to np.typing.ndarray can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: What is the `mypy` config status? Do you have: `[mypy]`
`plugins = numpy.typing.mypy_plugin`
in your `mypi.ini` in CircleCI ? Can you `import numpy.typing` without failures in CircleCI?

Comment: No, in circleci, import numpy.typing raised the module not found error. And no, I did not have the plugin in mypy (:/). After further digging, I've realized that I can also not import numpy.typing locally. For whatever reason mypy was passing locally despite that. And also remotely. What failed was the import of numpy.typing. Does numpy.typing not get imported out of the box? do I need to install a plugin? I thought the plugin was  for python 3.7 or older. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, I am reading the documentation properly, and it says that I need to add the plugin to mypy. Thank you norok2. But why would import numpy.typing raise the module not found error?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I have to do something like: `import numpy.typing as npt`
in addition to my standard numpy import. I can then use the `npt` alias for all my type hints. Before I made that change I would get the ImportError whenever I tried to run my code.